# How to load html in <iFrame>

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iframe, asp.net-mvc-2

I am storing html of error pages of my site in sql table, i want to display them in a  window, on the admin side, but not able to load the saved html in iframe, i am using asp.net mvc2.

its needed to save the pages, and display later to admin.

please suggest me right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more context and tell us what you have already tried. Simply asking for a solution usually isn't (and shouldn't) be enough.

Comment: i have tried jquery 

$("#iframeid").html('<%= item.content %>')

question is simple, i want to load saved html into iframe.

Comment: @user310657: Why don't you just download it into `div`? Why iframe? `iframe` shows content of url specified in `src` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it in an iframe, just write a severside script that takes this HTML and wraps it in a HTML doc dynamically: .... etc. Make this script publicly visible and pass some params to tell it what to display:

http://www.foo.com/iframescript.asp?html_display_params=saved_html

then:

```
<iframe src="http://www.foo.com/iframescript.... 

or: $('#iframeid').attr('src', 'http://www.foo.com/iframescript.asp....
```

you get the idea....

iframe means another url location, if you want to view something in an iframe it has to be it's own page.....

otherwise you want a normal frame.